Any way around macOS snapshot tidemarks?
I am using macOS Sequoia on Intel based Mac. I have 40GB of free space currently, and I wanted to partition the drive to allocate some more space for my Bootcamp volume. Disk utility only lets me allocate 10GB instead of 40GB and it says "Snapshot tidemarks can raise the minimum size above the used size.". I have only one snapshot and it can not be deleted, I have tried it from Terminal. This is something I have not seen on older OS versions and I am absolutely frustrated by this. There's nothing I can do about it?
The interesting part is, the snapshot behaves like a half alive half dead being that actually lets me use all of my free space on my Macintosh drive but at the same time acts like it is taking up space when it comes to partitioning… Should I free up like 150GB of space on my Mac drive so that I can make the partitioning I want?
